# Stored procedure ERROR in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Getstudentname(
    @firstname varchar(20),
    @lastname varchar (20),
    @e_mail varchar(20)
)
as
begin
    insert into TBL_STUDENTS(fanme, lname, email)
    values(@firstname, @lastname, @e_mail);
end;
```

What can be the error in this procedure?

Procedure GETSTUDENTNAME compiled

Errors:

> check compiler log

And this SQL query is also not working giving:

> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: CREATE TABLE  tbl_Students

(
   id int, fanme varchar(20), Lname varchar(20),Email varchar(20)
);

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't use `@` for parameters.  I would highly recommend that you prefix them with something, to distinguish them from column names.  Something like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Getstudentname (
    in_firstname varchar2,
    in_lastname varchar2,
    in_e_mail varchar2
)
as
begin
    insert into tbl_students(fname, lname, email)
         values(in_firstname, in_lastname, in_e_mail);
end;
```

In addition, Oracle does not require a length for string parameters, and `varchar2` is the standard variable string type.  Your code looks more like SQL Server code than Oracle code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Getstudentname(
firstname in varchar2,
lastname in varchar2,
e_mail in varchar2
)
as
begin
insert into TBL_STUDENTS(fanme,lname,email)values(firstname,lastname,e_mail);
end;
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-To-Write-a-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Correct the typos and use the right syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Students
( id int, Fname varchar(20), Lname varchar(20),Email varchar(20) );


create or replace PROCEDURE Getstudentname(
  firstname in tbl_students.fname%TYPE,
  lastname in tbl_students.lname%TYPE,
  e_mail in tbl_students.email%TYPE
)
as
begin
  insert into TBL_STUDENTS (fname,lname,email) values (firstname,lastname,e_mail );
end;
/
```